# jQuery dialog not firing if I add validation

Tags: c#, validation, jquery-dialog

I want to popup a jquery dialog form to allow user to fill in their data. The dialog is not firing when I click on a link_button if I add validation to some of fields in the dialog. However, it will popup if I remove those validation. Anyone can explain and solve my problem? I am new.

I put my jquery in my code behind:

```
protected void link_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = @"$('#createDialog').dialog({modal:true, show:'fold',
        hide:'fold'});";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", script, true);
}
```

I take on sample of my textbox from my table:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="passwordLabel" runat="server" Text="Password:">
        </asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="passwordBox" runat="server" CausesValidation="False">
        </asp:TextBox>  
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="passwordValidator" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="This is a mandatory field" 
            ControlToValidate="passwordBox"  ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic"   
            Font-Size="0.7em">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701081/cannot-call-jquery-dialog-from-code-when-there-is-validation-in-the-front